# Guzzlephp promise variable

Tags: php, guzzle

I need to pass a variable into the return of promise

```
<?php
$var = 'test';
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://url/');
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->then(function ($response) {
  $echo $var;
});
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: `$echo $var;` ?

Answer (score 4):

Is this not an option?
`

```
<?php

$var = 'test';
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://url/');
$promise = $client
    ->sendAsync($request, $options)
    ->then(
        function ($response)  use ( $var ) {
            echo $var;
        }
    );
$promise->wait();
```

`

Comment: To anyone interested here is a useful links for closure in php 
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Thank you, I was able to insert the variable